# How do I check the status of nominations for a staking account?

Tags: staking

I've used `await api.query.staking.nominators(address)` but that just returns something like:

```
{
    "result": {
        "targets": [
            "{nominatorId1}",
            "{nominatorId2}"
        ],
        "submittedIn": 4957,
        "suppressed": false
    }
}
```

This is useful but I don't know the statuses of each of them. Thank you!

Comment: What does "status" mean? What kinds of status do you want?

Comment: My colleague posted this because my IP address is blocked for some reason... Status meaning if the nomination is "active", "inactive", or "waiting". https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000169209-what-does-active-inactive-waiting-mean-

Comment: Micheal, does that article not provide the answers here? I would be happy to upvote the answer and proposed edits to the question to refine it :)

Comment: Thanks Dan! I'm wondering how to access that information programmatically from the API, not just through the browser portal. I think Xiu may have answered me though!

Answer (score 3):

Nominators active in a specific era -

```
const VALIDATOR = "1..."
const NOMINATORS = ["1...", "1..."]

const opt_era_info = await api.query.staking.activeEra()
const val_exposure = await api.query.staking.erasStakers(
  opt_era_info.unwrap().index,
  VALIDATOR
)

console.log(
  val_exposure.others
    .filter(o =>
      NOMINATORS.some(n =>
        o.who.eq(n)
      )
    )
    .map(n =>
      `${n.who.toString()} => ${n.value.toString()}`
    )
    .join("\n")

)
```

Those inactive are the reverse, not in a specific era.